# Trouble executing multiple-table mysql query from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064, multiple-tables

I am attempting to match rows in a mysql table using the values from `table1.column1` and `table2.column3` and then copy the value from `table2.column2` into `table1.column1` for each match. The query below does what I need to do, but only when I execute it manually (through phpmyadmin). When I try to execute it from PHP I receive the error `Unknown column table1.column1 in 'field list'`. Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($data);

$sql = "UPDATE table1 t1, table2 t2 
        SET t1.column1 = t2.column2 
        WHERE t1.column1 = t2.column3";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) {
  echo mysql_error();
} ?>
```

I know that the mysql connection info works because I am able to execute other queries. From my research on the error it seems that I might need backticks around some part of the query but after several tries I can't figure out the correct way.

**EDIT 1** - As requested here is the real query:

```
UPDATE wp_mf_custom_groups,wp_mf_posttypes
SET wp_mf_custom_groups.post_type=wp_mf_posttypes.type
WHERE wp_mf_custom_groups.post_type=wp_mf_posttypes.id
```

Outputs the error

```
Unknown column 'wp_mf_custom_groups.post_type' in 'field list'
```

Additional information I just realized might be conflicting with it. Before this happens I also renamed the table using:

```
RENAME TABLE wp_mf_module_groups TO wp_mf_custom_groups
```

Maybe since the table was just renamed it cant reference it?

Comment: Back ticks are only necessary if you're using a reserved word as a field or table name. Randomly sprinkling them around the query will NOT help. Did you doublecheck if your table1 contains a `column1` field?

Comment: You need to include your table schema.

Comment: @Crontab: Not if the two tables are in the same database and that's the database that is selected.

Comment: Are you sure you're connecting to the right database? Not some older version elsewhere? Using the right database?

Comment: I think perhaps in your question you meant to say "using the values from table1.column1 and table2.column**3**." Otherwise, what's the point of copying table2.column2 into table1.column1 when they already match?

Comment: @Travesty3: I mean he needs to include the schema (and preferably the real query) in his post.  I doubt his tables are named "table1" and "table2", and I doubt his columns are named "column1" etc.  This obfuscation is probably covering up the real issue.

Comment: @Travesty3 you're right. I edited the original post to be correct.

Comment: @Crontab I'll update soon with the real info. Was trying to simplify but maybe that made things harder :)

Comment: The `Unknown column` error tells me that the field doesn't exist in `wp_mf_custom_groups`.  I know you said it works if you do it as a raw query through phpMyAdmin - perhaps use the "Create PHP code" button there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked when I added backticks to the columns only after `WHERE`

```
UPDATE wp_mf_custom_groups,wp_mf_posttypes
SET wp_mf_custom_groups.post_type=wp_mf_posttypes.type
WHERE wp_mf_custom_groups.`post_type=wp_mf_posttypes.id
```

Answer (score 0):

If query works with PHPmyadmin try this

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass) or die('Failed to connect');
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('db_name', $con);

$sql = "UPDATE table1 t1, table2 t2 
    SET t1.column1 = t2.column2 
    WHERE t1.column1 = t2.column3";

$result = mysql_query($sql, $con);

if (!$result) {
  echo mysql_error();
} ?>
```